# emails not arriving

Tags: emails

I have this code to send an email from a form but nothing is arriving and I have no idea why. It looks fine to me

```
function enquiry_form_form_submit($form, $form_state) {
    $strMail = '<!DOCTYPE html>';
    $strMail = $strMail . '<head>';                                                                                             
    $strMail = $strMail . '<meta charset="UTF-8">';                             
    $strMail = $strMail . '<title>Studiga</title>';
    $strMail = $strMail . '</head>';                                                                                    
    $strMail = $strMail . '<body>';                     
    $strMail =  "Dear Landlord<br><br>";
    $strMail = $strMail . "You've been sent an enquiry about one of your properties:<br><br>";  
    $strMail = $strMail . "Name: " . trim($form_state['values']['name']) . "<br>";  
    $strMail = $strMail . "Email: " . trim($form_state['values']['email']) . "<br>";
    $strMail = $strMail . "Telephone: " . trim($form_state['values']['telephone']) . "<br>";
    $strMail = $strMail . "Room information: " . trim($form_state['values']['room_information']) . "<br>";  
    $strMail = $strMail . "Room information:<br><br>" . trim($form_state['values']['enquiry']) . "<br>";
    $strMail = $strMail . "<br><br>Regards,<br>Studiga team";           
    $strMail = $strMail . "</body>";
    $To_Email = trim($form_state['values']['contact_email']);
    $To_Email = "pamela@gconnect.com";
    $params = array(
        'subject' => "Studiga room enquiry",
        'body' => $strMail,
    );

    $email_from = trim($form_state['values']['name']) . "<" . trim($form_state['values']['email'])  . ">";
    $result = drupal_mail('enquiry_form', 'room', $To_Email, language_default(), $params, $email_from);
    if ($result['result'] == TRUE) {
        drupal_goto('http://studiga.delta-xray.co.uk/enquiry-thank-you');   
    }
    else {
        $Msg = "<div>There has been a problem sending the errors Email</div>";
        echo $Msg;  
    }
}

function enquiry_form_mail($key, &$message, $params){

  $message['headers']['Content-Type'] = 'text/html; charset=UTF-8; format=flowed';

  $message['subject'] = $params['subject'];
  $message['body'][] = $params['body']; 

}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The drupal_mail() statement looks fine.

Check your site database logs at "**Admin => Reports => Recent Log messages (If not available install "Database Logging" module)**" if message is successfully sent or not. If it is failed, then you need to check if your server is properly configured to send an emails from. If not, then you can setup [Postfix](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-postfix-as-a-send-only-smtp-server-on-ubuntu-14-04) to send emails from server.

**Updates:**
You can also try installing and configuring [SMTP](https://www.drupal.org/project/smtp) module in your Site. The module allows to send email from Drupal Site without setting up Postfix on Server.

Answer (score 0):

There could be many reasons for emails not to arrive, like [SPF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework#Implementation) and [DKIM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DomainKeys_Identified_Mail) records on your domain. (I've had particular issues with Google Apps domains where the mail would not even reach the spam folder.)

What worked for me in the past is to install the [SMTP module](https://www.drupal.org/project/smtp). It's a lot easier to install than postfix and allows you to send mails through an external authenticated mail server (so SPF and DKIM become of less importance). You can for instance use this with an @gmail account.

Comment: It is Drupal 7 and there is nothing in Admin => Reports => Recent Log messages

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using Drupal 8 (in which case I am reasonably sure your code would cause errors, but at the very least not work), then it's most certainly a server configuration issue (i.e. you don't have an MTA such as sendmail or Postfix installed).  [Using the SMTP module](https://www.knthost.com/drupal/send-email-using-smtp-drupal-7) would be a quick way to validate your code itself versus spending a few hours to set up and configure Postfix.

Answer (score 0):

$result = drupal_mail('enquiry_form', 'room', $To_Email, language_default(), $params, $email_from);

should have been

$result = drupal_mail('enquiry_form', 'room', $To_Email, language_default(), $params, $email_from,TRUE);

i was hoping it would do an HTML Email but I see you can't in Drupal 7 without https://www.drupal.org/project/htmlmail